# Achieving antique/sepia photo filter with CSS

Tags: css

I need help achieving an antique photo filter using pure CSS. I am trying to achieve the color only and not the pixelation or broken edges effect. I know the pixelation and tear cannot be achieved with CSS but I am hoping to get as close as possible with the color/contrast/saturation/etc. Here is the goal:

[image]

So far I have this code:

```css
filter: sepia(.75) contrast(.75) brightness(1.25) saturate(1.4);
```

My other problem is the color accuracy of my monitor is not so good, so I'm hoping someone with better calibrated monitor can help out achieving it.

Comment: This post looks like it belongs to Fiver or some freelancing site.
To achieve this alone with CSS would take a lot of coding, especially the distortions on the image. If you want an easy solution, get a svg or png and place it on top the image.

Comment: I forgot to add, that I was trying to achieve the color only and not the pixelation or broken edges effect. You are right, this result is from a website that does that to image. Although I am hoping for a pure css color that is as close as possible to that result

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hmmm, try this solution, 2 layers of filters and a radial background gradient. Keep hitting "Run code snippet" to load a different image

I've edited this answer like 10 times now. Look through the revisions for various different combinations of filters and so on, personally I think this current iteration is the nicest, it keeps the same darkness and it doesn't completely white wash the light areas, it's probably far off replicating the filter from the example, I think iteration 5 or 6 was closest to the colouring of the sample

```css
/* IGNORE THESE SYLES */
body { margin: 0 } section { display: flex; gap: 5px; padding: 5px } .media > * { display: block; max-width: 100% }



/* CSS FOR ANSWER BELOW */
.sepiaEffect {
  background: radial-gradient(circle at center, rgb(205, 165, 105), rgb(100, 80, 60) 84%);
  filter: contrast(132%) saturate(180%);
}

.sepiaEffect > * {
  filter: opacity(60%) saturate(0%) sepia(30%);
}
```

```html
<section>
<div class="media">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/1200/900">
</div>
<div class="media sepiaEffect">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/1200/900">
</div>
</section>
```

Comment: The [current iteration of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/73007842/3) is close, but I think it also needs some slight negative [hue rotation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/hue-rotate). Nice job on addressing the [vignetting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vignetting): it's an important artifact of the commonly-used lenses from the "antique" cameras which produced the photos we associate with this style.

Comment: @jsejcksn hue shift in which direction? Which color do you expect to see more of?

Comment: I mentioned _negative_ as the direction in the first comment because it seemed _a bit_ too yellow (to my eyes on the display I used to view the demo) — but you've edited the answer several times since I wrote that comment, and, of course, It's always going to be subjective to the viewer.